# Invalid column error even when column exists in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, join

```
SELECT 
    S.EY_BNF_ADDR,S.[EY_BNF_COUNTRY], [Expected Country Code]
FROM 
    STG_TRXN S
JOIN 
    CCD_NULL_BNF C ON C.EY_BNF_ADDR = S.EY_BNF_ADDR
```

I am getting

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'EY_BNF_ADDR'.

For above query on the join column, but when I run select on the join columns separately, they run fine. This is so weird. One join column is `varchar(765) null` and other is `varchar(8000) null`

Here is the structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCD_NULL_BNF]
(
    [EY_ BNF_ADDR] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [EY_BNF_COUNTRY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Expected Country Code] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I apologize for pasting the huge structure of below table -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STG_TRXN]
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EY_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SOURCE_FILE] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ACC_NO] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ACC_TYPE] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CR_ACC_NO] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CR_ACC_TYP] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [SERVICE] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [VALUE_DATE] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [AMOUNT] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [OGB] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [OGB_ID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [OGB_BIC] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [OGB_ADDR1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [OGB_ADDR2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [OGB_ADDR3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ORG] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ORG_ID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ORG_ADDR1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ORG_ADDR2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ORG_ADDR3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ORG_BIC] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [OBI] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BBI] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [OUTSERVICE] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [DIRECTION] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [MID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [LOCAL_REF] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [IBK] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [IBK_ADDR1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [IBK_ADDR2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [IBK_ADDR3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [IBK_BIC] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BNF] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BNF_ADDR1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BNF_ADDR2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BNF_ADDR3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BNF_BIC] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BNF_ID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BBK] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BBK_BIC] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BBK_ADDR1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BBK_ADDR2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BBK_ADDR3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [COUNTRYCODE] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [orig_rfb] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_IBK_ADDR1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_IBK_ADDR2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_IBK_ADDR3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_OGB_ADDR1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_OGB_ADDR2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_OGB_ADDR3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_ORG_ADDR1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_ORG_ADDR2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_ORG_ADDR3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BNF_ADDR1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BNF_ADDR2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BNF_ADDR3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BBK_ADDR1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BBK_ADDR2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BBK_ADDR3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_IBK_COUNTRY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_OGB_COUNTRY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BNF_COUNTRY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BBK_COUNTRY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_OGB] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_ORG] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BNF] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_OBI] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BBI] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [IS_DELETE] [bit] NULL,
    [CREATE_DT] [datetime] NULL,
    [UPDATE_DT] [datetime] NULL,
    [IS_MOVED] [char](1) NULL,
    [IS_MOVED_DT] [datetime] NULL,
    [COMMENT] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BNF_BANK_COUNTRY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ORG_BANK_COUNTRY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [INTER_BANK_COUNTRY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_OGB_ADDR] [varchar](765) NULL,
    [EY_BNF_ADDR] [varchar](765) NULL,
    [EY_IBK_ADDR] [varchar](765) NULL,
    [EY_ORG_ADDR] [varchar](765) NULL,
    [EY_ORG_COUNTRY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BBK_ADDR] [varchar](800) NULL,
    [EY_ORG_ID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BNF_ID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_ORG_PARTY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EY_BNF_PARTY] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Does anybody know what is happening?

Comment: can you provide the structure of `STG_TRXN`?

Comment: ... And for the other table too.

Comment: Are either of those tables (`STG_TRXN` and `CCD_NULL`) views or stored procedures? And where does `[Expected Country Code]` come from?

Comment: @MartinSmith  - Added table structures. Expected Country Code comes from CCD_NULL_BNF table.

Comment: Storing things like dates and amounts as varchar(255) is a horrible practice which will cause you serious problems later on, for example when sorting or doing range searches.

Comment: Thanks @JamesZ! It is a raw table which is just used to data storage. Clean data gets populated into other tables, but I will keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCD_NULL_BNF](
    [EY_ BNF_ADDR] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [EY_BNF_COUNTRY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Expected Country Code] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Notice `[EY_ BNF_ADDR]`  There is a space after the `EY_`

You can see the error duplicated [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/653fe/1)  Fixed [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de331/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove space in field name [EY_BNF_ADDR] :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCD_NULL_BNF]
(
    [EY_BNF_ADDR] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [EY_BNF_COUNTRY] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Expected Country Code] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```